# DataDog Pro pricing plan wrt RDS metric

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, cloud, amazon-rds, datadog

currently have an RDS instance in AWS that I want to monitor for CPU and freeable memory metrics using DataDog. My main concern is whether I need to pay the per-agent cost of $15 per host, even though I only need to monitor two metrics of a single RDS instance. Can I use the same agent to monitor additional RDS instances that I might create in the future, and will the cost remain the same or increase based on the number of RDS instances I monitor?
btw, cloudwatch is out of the picture as we are using single pain of class model for observaility